# Changing tabHost & Rank selection color

Tags: java, android, image

I want to change the Blue color of the selection in the tabHost and in the Rank star...anyone know how do I can do that ?

Thanks

The Following image... [image]

Comment: See this good tutorial about customizing Tab View : [link](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136)

Comment: Hello!

I don't find a solution for my problem in this tutorial...

tyvm

Comment: It's in the tab_bg_selector.xml where you can set the color of the selected tab. Or maybe I didn't understand what you are looking for, if it is so, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add selector code in drawable folder file_name "**selector.xml**"

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- When selected, color is white -->
    <item  android:color="@android:color/white"
          android:state_selected="true" />
<!-- When not selected, color is green -->
    <item  android:color="@android:color/green" />
</selector>
```

Set this selector in your main file like this

```
TabSpec tabSpecWindow = tabHost.setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.selector))
          .setContent(new Intent(  ,  ));
```

Changing the color of rating bar has similar process to selection color change Tabhost
Get the star images of color which you want.
create color.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/color_empty" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress" android:drawable="@drawable/color_half" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/color_full" />
</layer-list>
```

Now in your rating bar add below code

```
<RatingBar android:progressDrawable="@drawable/color"/>
```

Comment: Refer this Tutorial [link](http://adanware.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-custom-tab-layouts-just-using.html)

Comment: I did exaclty the same of the tutorial...but the tab layout only stay the same...